# I need to convert docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph object to string in python

Tags: python-docx

I need to convert to string. Here is my code

single_para = doc.paragraphs[1]

str(single_para)

Answer (score 0):

Use `doc.paragraphs[1].text`. This returns the text of the paragraph as a string.

Comment: @WesleyOchoka welcome to StackOverflow. Don't neglect to accept a response that answers your question. That's how you thank the respondent for taking the time to answer and it also grows your reputation points. Just click the checkmark icon next to the answer.

Comment: Is there a way to read docx file  line by line, current implementation gets all the text in paragraph @scanny